# How do I solve a NetworkError when attempting to debug a React Native application?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am creating an Android React Native application and everything seems to be working fine except when I attempt to debug the program. When I attempt to do this, the app just becomes a blank white screen and the Chrome console has this error:

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true' failed to load.

A few seconds later the app crashes. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? I just started the project and I haven't really done that much yet so I don't know why this would be breaking

Comment: what version of react native are you running?

Comment: I'm getting this now with RN 0.17.0 while trying to debug a packaged app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The reason I've come across that error, is because I was running with chrome debugging enabled. Turning that off solved the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. This is how I solved it.

In **AppDelegate.m** I had **commented** -

jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];

**and uncommented -**

jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

Did this to run on device. Switched it back. Works now.